# Why can't I run a node.js file in crontab?

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, cron

I'm trying to setup a crontab on a macOS machine to run a node.js script.

I have tried both to:

1. Make a shell script that points to both the absolute path of my node.js file and node itself to run the node.js script and have it run by crontab
2. Have the command with absolute paths written out in crontab itself

the absolute path I was using for node was: /usr/local/bin/node

Anyone might have any idea as to why the cron job can't execute this but when I'm running the shell script or the command myself it does work?

Thanks in advance

***edit:***

I have added an output log as was suggested by **l'L'l**.
it seems like a node error but can't seem to understand why this is happening only when its run by the crontab

```
internal/fs/utils.js:230
throw err;
^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/Users/myuser/Desktop/puppeteer/index.js'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:22)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    errno: -1,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'EPERM',
    path: '/Users/myuser/Desktop/puppeteer/index.js'
}
```

Comment: Show the actual crontab command you are attempting.

Comment: I've changed it a few times but its a variant of this:
*/1 * * * * /Users/myuser/Desktop/puppeteer/run.sh

Comment: What owner/permissions does the script have?

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 myuser  staff      71 Apr 19 01:27 run.sh

Comment: And what about /use/local/bin/node?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72926880 Mar 26 21:45 /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: Looks like you need to add execute permission to run.sh. If that doesn't solve it, capture output & errors from the script by adding something like `>/tmp/run.log 2>&1` at the end of the crontab entry. See [the canonical cron troubleshooting question over on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it).

Comment: well I tried solving it and all I got is a node error and can't find useful Information about it... Any chance you understand what's going on? ill add it to the question

Comment: @JohnD: Try doing `chmod +x run.sh`.